# DI ILogger with Serilog on Webapi 2 running Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I am trying to integrate Serilog to my WebApi 2 with Asp.Net Core 2 (With MSSQLServer integration).

I have added the nuget packages and then added the following to my

`public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)`

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase, "Logs")
                .CreateLogger();

loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

The in my `Program.cs` I have the default;

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

From reading the MSDN docs `.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` should include logging?

However, when I then DI the `ILogger` to my controller;

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TraderController : Controller
{
    private TraderService _service;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TraderController(Func<IBemfeitoDataContext> context, ILogger logger)
    {
        _service = new TraderService(context, logger);
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

I am getting the following error;

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.Controllers.TraderContactController'.

Do I need to physically setup a singleton for `ILogger` in the Startup.cs. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? As I assumed because logging is build into the Core pipeline this would be something it knew how to resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refactor the controller to expect the generic logger `ILogger<T>`, which is derived from `ILogger`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TraderController : Controller {
    private TraderService _service;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TraderController(
            Func<IBemfeitoDataContext> context, 
            ILogger<TraderController> logger //<-- note the change here
    ) { 
        _service = new TraderService(context, logger);
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

`ILogger<>` is mapped to `Logger<>` when [`.AddLogging()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32) is called within `CreateDefaultBuilder`. `ILogger` is not registered directly with the service collection.

With that done, the current design choice of coupling the controller to implementation concerns (i.e `TraderService`) was a cause for some concern.

assuming based on how the current code is being used

```
public class TraderService : ITraderService {
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TraderService(Func<IBemfeitoDataContext> context, ILogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;

        //...
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

the service should also be fixed to depend on `ILogger<T>`

```
public class TraderService : ITraderService {
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TraderService(Func<IBemfeitoDataContext> context, ILogger<TraderService> logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
        //...
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

and the controller should be refactored to depend on the service abstraction and not the implementation.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TraderController : Controller {
    private readonly ITraderService service;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TraderController(ITraderService service, ILogger<TraderController> logger) { 
        this.service = service;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    //...
}
```

All classes involved will get their dependencies explicitly injected when resolved.

This answer assumes that `ITraderService` and `TraderService` are registered with the DI container.

Comment: Thats great, thanks for clearing that up, as its being typed does this have any effect on the logger being passed down to my `TraderService`?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn Assuming `TraderService` is asking for `ILogger` and is not expected to be resolved via the DI container, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn I was curious as to why it was being explicitly created and not injected into the controller though.

Comment: Sorry can you expand a bit? Am I approaching this wrongly? If theres a better way of doing this its a greenfield project so I can change it

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for pointing that out makes sense now. Just to check I would then register each service in the Startup.cs `services.AddTransient<ITraderService, TraderService>();` etc?

Answer (score 1):

Both **`ILoggerFactory`** and generic `ILogger<T>` are injected. That means you could have your controller like this:

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class TraderController : Controller {
       private readonly ITraderService service;
       private readonly ILogger logger;
       public TraderController(ITraderService service, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
       { 
           this.service = service;
           this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TraderController>();
       }
       //...
   }
```